# Deriving values from SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL Server stored procedure that basically returns a derived value from an outcome of a function call. The  derived field returns the difference in days and if the difference is less than 24 hours then returns hours. It is working as desired but just need to ensure if the approach is right.

Stored procedure query:

```
SELECT ua.ID AS UserAgreementID
          , A.ID AS AgreementID
          , A.Code
          , A.ComplianceCode
          , A.Name
          , A.Description
          , A.Version
          , ua.UserAgreementStateID
          , uas.Name AS UserAgreementStateName
          , ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry
          , declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry) AS NoOfDays
          , A.Data
          , pa.ID AS AuthoredByID
          , pa.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS AuthoredByName
          , A.Authored
          , ia.ID AS IssuedByID
          , ia.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS IssuedByName
          , A.Issued
        FROM declaration.Agreement AS A
        INNER JOIN declaration.UserAgreement AS ua
            ON A.ID = ua.AgreementID
        INNER JOIN declaration.UserAgreementState AS uas
            ON ua.UserAgreementStateID = uas.ID
        LEFT JOIN common.Person AS pa
            ON A.AuthoredBy = pa.ID
        LEFT JOIN common.Person AS ia
            ON A.IssuedBy = ia.ID
        WHERE ua.UserID = 607
        AND uas.Code IN ('ISS', 'DEF') -- Issued, Deferred
        AND A.Draft = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not a draft.
        AND A.Deleted = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not deleted.
        AND ISNULL(A.Issued, '9999-12-31') <= GETUTCDATE() -- Issued date less than equal to today's date (Issued date).   
        AND ISNULL(A.Expires, '9999-12-31') > GETUTCDATE()
```

I have tried writing a function and not sure if it is correctly written. How do I call this function from within the query

```
CREATE FUNCTION declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS int   
AS   

BEGIN  
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInDays INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInHours INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifference INT;

    SELECT @timeDifferenceInDays = DATEDIFF(d,  GETUTCDATE(), @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
    IF @timeDifferenceInDays > 1
      BEGIN
            SELECT @timeDifference = @timeDifferenceInDays
       END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifferenceInHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,  GETUTCDATE(),  @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
          IF @timeDifferenceInHours >= 0 AND @timeDifferenceInHours <= 24
             BEGIN 
                SELECT @timeDifference = @timeDifferenceInHours
             END
          ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @timeDifference = -1
          END
        END
        RETURN @timeDifference;  
    END;
```

Comment: The implementation is no different no a normal `SELECT`, simply include in in the query as an expression in the `SELECT`. Not sure I follow what the problem is here.

Comment: On a different note, you should avoid things like `AND ISNULL(A.Expires, '9999-12-31') > GETUTCDATE() ` in the `WHERE`. Use proper boolean logic and handle your `NULL`s with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. For the expression i quoted, that would therefore mean `AND (A.Expires > GETUTCDATE() OR A.Expires IS NULL)`. Wrapping the column in `ISNULL` will make the query non-SARGable, which will effect performance.

Comment: @Larnu , the A.Expires is an existing field in the table and is used for a different purpose. I need a compute column such as NoOfDays that I have done. The main thing I need is that logic should determine the requirement that i have mentioned above. Basically if the difference is > 1 then return no of days and if difference is greater that 0 and less than 24 hours return hours

Comment: @larnu , I hope it is clear to you.

Comment: @larnu , is it better encapsulating it in a function and calling it within the query

Comment: My point about `ISNULL` has nothing to do with the usage of the column. Don't wrap columns with `ISNULL` in the `WHERE`, use proper Boolean logic.

Comment: @Tom SQL Server is a relational database management system, not a programming environment like Java and .NET Framework. Encapsulating regularly used logic in functions, while logical from a DRY programming perspective, actually works against you in SQL Server (particularly older versions) because the query planner has little to no insight into user-defined functions and estimates them with a low cost. This can cause QP to make bad decisions on how to use tables and indexes and yield negative performance implications on queries in general.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for letting me know. Could you guide me then how to use logic written in my function with my stored procedure sql

Comment: @larnu, are you saying  AND ISNULL(A.Expires, '9999-12-31') > GETUTCDATE() is the same as AND (A.Expires > GETUTCDATE() OR A.Expires IS NULL)
in terms of output but latter is better at performance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review. There is a different site for this.

Comment: Where do I post it ?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying, @Tom .

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/